# In Corda, liquibase.exception.SetupException: migration/account-application.changelog-master.xml does not exist

Tags: corda

I have migrated from Corda Open-Source to Corda Enterprise (by adding the JARs to my local maven repository for Gradle) and made some minor adjustments to my OS project to cater for versioning. I have also created all the migration scripts but have run into a wall regarding the placement of these scripts.

I believe the scripts should be placed in the `resources` folder so they automatically get included in the build. I have also tried including them in the base directory for a node. However, I cannot work out the process surrounding the placement of the .xml files as I keep getting the `liquibase.exception.SetupException: migration/account-application.changelog-master.xml does not exist` error below:

> [ERROR] 18:01:08+1000 [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node
>   startup  liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing
>   master.changelog.json at
>   liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:98)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:229)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.Liquibase.listUnrunChangeSets(Liquibase.java:1183)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.Liquibase.listUnrunChangeSets(Liquibase.java:1176)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration(SchemaMigration.kt:133)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.doRunMigration$default(SchemaMigration.kt:77)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.checkState(SchemaMigration.kt:66)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.SchemaMigration.nodeStartup(SchemaMigration.kt:49)
>   ~[corda-node-api-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNodeKt.configureDatabase(AbstractNode.kt:1140)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.initialiseDatabasePersistence(AbstractNode.kt:852)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.Node.initialiseDatabasePersistence(Node.kt:373)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:296)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:387)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.EnterpriseNode.start(EnterpriseNode.kt:181)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:270)
>   ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at
>   net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:160)
>   [corda-node-3.1.jar:?] at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:25)
>   [corda-node-3.1.jar:?] Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException:
>   migration/account-application.changelog-master.xml does not exist at
>   liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:322)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:282)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] at
>   liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:91)
>   ~[liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar:?] ... 16 more

Where should I place the scripts and .xml files?

Answer (score 1):

Your migration scripts should be placed under `resources/migration`, and not at the top level of the `resources` folder.